# Alternative to New Relic for pinging Heroku application

Tags: node.js, heroku, newrelic

I'm running a Node.js app on Heroku for free. People use New Relic for pinging their app constantly, preventing the dyno from idling, but New Relic does not support Node. Does anyone know of an alternative add-on that supports Node? I don't care about features, I just need it to ping once every <1 hr.

Comment: There are e.g. [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) and [Monitis](http://portal.monitis.com/) that can help you ping an app often enough to prevent dyno idling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com) should work for that. The [Heroku add-on catalog](https://addons.heroku.com/#monitoring) has lots of other monitoring add-ons that should also work great.

Answer (score 3):

**Tested and working on my own Heroku app using Node.js 0.10.x on 6/28/2013**

```
var http = require('http'); //importing http

function startKeepAlive() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var options = {
            host: 'your_app_name.herokuapp.com',
            port: 80,
            path: '/'
        };
        http.get(options, function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                try {
                    // optional logging... disable after it's working
                    console.log("HEROKU RESPONSE: " + chunk);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err.message);
                }
            });
        }).on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);
        });
    }, 20 * 60 * 1000); // load every 20 minutes
}

startKeepAlive();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also [uptime](https://github.com/fzaninotto/uptime) : a nice Node.js monitoring tool. Free, open source, extensible through plugins, must be installed manually. One can defines the "ping" frequency down to the second.